# Anti Sniff OR Sniff Detection

Tags: detection, sniffer

Does anyone know a "network sniffing detection" tool for linux?
Thank you.

Comment: You want to detect if someone's running a nmap (or similar tool) scan on your system? That would be an Intrusion Detection System, like Snort.

Comment: @MarcB: I don't think they are referring to scanners but machines that are sniffing network packets passively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To identify a network sniffer on your network use one of these tools to find machines operating in promiscuous mode.

1. [sniffdet](http://sniffdet.sourceforge.net/)
2. [Sniffer.Detectors](http://www.linux-sec.net/Sniffer.Detectors/)
3. [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/)